# Xcode analyze says 'Potential leak of an object'

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm a beginner and i found this warning here after running 'Analyze' on Xcode:

```
IphoneFeatureImageDetailViewController *img = [[IphoneFeatureImageDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"IphoneFeatureImageDetailViewController" bundle:nil];    
img.imagesArray = [heroArray copy];
img.index = imgButton.tag; // AT THIS LINE IT SAYS POTENTIAL MEMORY LEAK
[self.navigationController pushViewController:img animated:YES];
[img release];
```

Please point me in right direction!

Comment: You can ignore this in my opinion, since you're only assigning an integer value (index on img) to another `integer` value (`tag` of the `NSButton` I guess?).

Comment: imgButton is from the method signature 
- (void)imgDetail:(UIButton*)imgButton

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Analyze command often flags the line **after** the problem because that's the point in the code where it knows the leak has happened.  In your case, it's probably the `imagesArray` that it's reporting.  If that's a `retain` property then there will be one retain for the `copy` and another for the assignment, which is more than needed.

I suspect...

```
img.imagesArray = [[heroArray copy] autorelease];
```

...will clear it up.  Or you could switch to ARC and the whole problem would go away.  :)

Comment: thank you sir, putting autorelease in that line solved my problem :)

Comment: "The Analyze command often flags the line after the problem" awesome piece of information.